# run different versions of php on IIS for different websites - IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis

I have a `windows server 2012 R2 machine` and I want to host two websites on it. One is using `php7` and other using `php5.6`.

I have installed both version using [Microsoft Web Platform tool](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). Now I have `php manager`, from where I can change the `php` version of the site.

But when I change the version, the change also happen for all other sites. I want to change the `php` version for only the current site.

Please let me know if there is any workaround for this?

Comment: I managed to make it Work by following the configuration defined on following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-60-and-iis-7-and-above I hope, this help some one who would have same issue.